# Is is possible to put into clipboard the result of a shell command?

Tags: shell, unix, copy-paste, zsh

Imagine I do:

```
echo $PATH
```

in a terminal. Is is possible that the result is automatically copied so that if I do <kbd>Ctrl+y</kbd> it would get printed? As I understand it, when doing <kbd>Ctrl+k</kbd> on a terminal, the text is saved in a memory buffer that belongs to the terminal, so I would think something like this should be possible.

Any thoughts?

Comment: sorry, but what does that mean?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Depends. Linux, Mac or Windows?

The mac has the commands `pbcopy` and `pbpaste` to copy and paste something from the clipboard.

Copy example (mac):

```
echo $PATH | pbcopy
```

Paste Example (mac):

```
echo "$(pbpaste -Prefer txt)"
```

Linux uses X which has multiple copy-paste buffers (somewhat akin to the clipboard, but a little more involved).

You can use a little application like [XSel](http://www.kfish.org/software/xsel/) to copy/paste, The command would be used in the same form as the pbcopy/pbpaste

Copy:

```
echo $PATH | xsel --clipboard
```

'paste':

```
echo "$(xsel --output --clipboard)"
```

For windows, you can use an app like [clip](http://www.labnol.org/software/tutorials/copy-dos-command-line-output-clipboard-clip-exe/2506/), which allows the same copy/paste functionality

Copy:

```
set %PATH% | clip
```

I generally use Linux/Unix so I don't have the equivalent for pasting from the clipboard on Windows.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. I am also running on Linux. I'll put this into use immediately.

Comment: You can also use [`xclip`](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/commit/217c281abfbed48ee0c19c4b533f2aa9d5724429)

Comment: On Windows, in Powershell, use `Set-Clipboard`. For example, the equivalent of Mac's `pwd | pbcopy` on Windows is `Get-Location | Set-Clipboard`. Note that Powershell has a lot of aliases for short-hand commands, for example `pwd` is an alias for `Get-Location`, so `pwd | Set-Clipboard` will work in Powershell too.